# bbpress - Doesn't Post Replies/Topics

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I have setup a bbpress forum and I'm starting to style it, but when I try to reply to a topic, the button opens a new blank window and doesn't post the reply. I've tried disabling plugins, but it's not having any affect. What could this be?

http://matchedbetting.review/forums/forum/daily-offers/

user: guest
pass: guest124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflicting CSS with template which caused the issues.